# How do I configure the SAML NameID format in my IEF based IDP's Metadata?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to use Azure B2C's Identity Framework Experience to implement IdP initiated SAML SSO into a service provider.  The service provider requires the identity provider's metadata to have the `NameIDFormat` element in `IDPSSODescriptor` set to `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient`.

The problem I am having is that IEF does not seem to support configuring `NameIDFormat`.  It seems that the metadata IEF produces only supports `persistent`

The policy I am using is provided below. It is modeled directly after [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/connect-with-saml-service-providers) on implementing a SAML SSO policy in IEF.

I have tried to configure the `NameIDFormat` by setting IEF's `NameIdPolicyFormat` parameter [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-identity-provider-technical-profile#metadata) with no luck.

I also tried to set `SubjectNamingInfo` to a claim that is "transient-y" (ie randomly generated, ephemeral). I created a claims transformer that generates a random GUID claim and hoped that IEF would notice it was randomly generated and set the `NameIdFormat` accordingly.

Any suggestions on how to set my IDP's metadata's `NameIdFormat` to `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient` ?

**IEF SSO Policy**

```xml
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" TenantId="acmecorp.onmicrosoft.com" PolicyId="B2C_1A_signup_signin_saml" PublicPolicyUri="http://acmecorp.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin_saml" DeploymentMode="Development" UserJourneyRecorderEndpoint="urn:journeyrecorder:applicationinsights" TenantObjectId="...">
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>acmecorp.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="Saml2AssertionIssuerEncrypted" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>
  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
    <UserJourneyBehaviors>
      <SingleSignOn Scope="Application" />
      <SessionExpiryType>Absolute</SessionExpiryType>
      <SessionExpiryInSeconds>86400</SessionExpiryInSeconds>
    </UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="SAML2" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IdpInitiatedProfileEnabled">true</Item>
        <Item Key="NameIdPolicyFormat">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</Item>
        <Item Key="WantsEncryptedAssertions">true</Item>
        <Item Key="PartnerEntity"><![CDATA[
            <md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="https://the-sp.com" ID="...">
              <md:SPSSODescriptor ID="..." protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true">
                <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
                <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://the-sp.com/sso-endpoint" index="1" isDefault="true"/>
              </md:SPSSODescriptor>
            </md:EntityDescriptor>
              ]]></Item>
      </Metadata>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="UID" DefaultValue="never@never.com" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="UID" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. How did you manage to solve it?